# How do can you dynamically reload a custom component and pass it a new argument?

Tags: angular, components

Another newbie Angular question. I have a select with 3 options. When an option in the select is selected, I want the value of the option to be passed to the id argument of my custom component and for that component to refresh itself and display the value of the argument passed to it. Currently when I reset the value of the argument to mycustomcomponent nothing happens.

**app.component.html**

```
<select (change)="onDoSomethingWithChange($event.target.value)">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<mycustomcomponent #MyCustomComp [id]=0></mycustomcomponent>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
@ViewChild('MyCustomComp', {static: false}) myCustomComp: MyCustomComponent;

 public onDoSomethingWithChange(id : number):void
 {
    this.myCustomComp.id = id
 }
}
```

**mycustomcomponent.component.ts** (This component will simply take the id value passed to it and display it.)

```
export class MyCustomComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: number;
}
```

**mycustomcomponent.component.html**

```
 You passed an id of value {{id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it is kind of messy. You don't need to use `ViewChild` in order to pass an `id` to your component. The easiest solution should be like this:

```
APP COMPONENT

public id: number;

public onDoSomethingWithChange(id: number) {
  this.id = id
}
```

```
APP HTML

<mycustomcomponent [id]="id"></mycustomcomponent>
```

```
CUSTOM COMPONENT

export class MyCustomComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id: number;
}
```

For further information, refer to the Angular tutorial [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use "ViewChild" in order to pass the selected value to the child component.
you can have a property in your parent component that will hold the "selected value",
and on each update to the selected value, you update that value.
this property can be passed as the input to your child component.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xgrci9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)